# how to assign textbox value directly to session in codeigniter with out form

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

```
<input type="hidden" ID="lang" Class="form-control" value="English">
<?php  $this->session->set_userdata('user_lang', 'Arabic');?>
```

On dropdown change the textbox value get changed i need to assign this textbox value to session without any form in codeigniter

Comment: Since PHP runs on the server you're going to need to send that value up to the server somehow - Ajax is probably your best bet if you're not wanting to use a form for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to trigger the change of value. and then run an ajax to set session data

```
$('#lang').change(function(){
   var val = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
       url: "<?=site_url('your_controller/your_method')?>",
       type: "POST",
       data: {val: val},
       success: function(res){
          // your code after the ajax completed
       }
   });
});
```

now at controller create a new method which will set session data

```
functoin your_method(){
   $this->session->set_userdata('user_lang', $this->input->post('val'));
}
```

Comment: It's not working i m not going to chnage textbox value i have butto toggle dropdown its changable value only available in the textbox